# href="javascript:true" unexpected behaviour

Tags: html

```
<html>
   <body>
     <a href="javascript:helloWorld()" >Hello world</a>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function helloWorld(){
            console.log("Hello world");
            return true;
        }
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

If open this page in firefox(not happening in chrome) and click on the link, I will get back new empty page, with "true" as a content. Why is this happening? Is this a expected behaviour or a bug. Although I was able to fix it by replacing it with `helloWorld();void(0);`.

Comment: Your question states "unexpected behaviour" but you've not stated what behaviour you *were* expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

The `javascript:` URL scheme is *designed* so you can generate content from JavaScript and have it rendered as a new page.

Using it to trigger effects on the current page is a hack.

---

If you want to trigger events on the current page then use [a *click* event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead (and use a button instead of a link if you aren't going to have a fail-state of "visiting another page").

Comment: What I'm wondering is why isn't this same behavior happening on Chrome browser?

Answer (score 2):

When the browser navigates to a `javascript:` URI, the code is evaluated and it's return value (the return value of the last expression) is used: If it's `undefined`, the the browser doesn't navigate, else the browser navigates to a page with the content of the conversion of that value to a string.

Since `helloWorld()` returns true and it's the last expression in your code, the browser creates a page with `"true"` as its content. `void(0)` returns `undefined`, so it doesn't navigate.

---

I recommend not using hyperlinks for triggering actions. That's not what they were made for. From the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#hyperlink):

> [Hyperlinks] are links to other resources that are generally exposed to the user by the user agent so that the user can cause the user agent to navigate to those resources, e.g. to visit them in a browser or download them.

That's not what you're doing. Use the `<button>` element instead and style it like a link.